# Trying to send data in the body of a Axios GET to use in Django backend, but print of request.body is empty

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

According the Axios, this should be possible:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/462#issuecomment-252075124

I have the following and `pos_title` does have a value.

```
export function getQuery(pos_code, id) {
    if (id === 94) {
        var strArray = pos_code.split(' - ');
        pos_code = strArray[0];
        var pos_title = strArray[1];
    }
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get(
            `${URL}/api/survey/${(id)}/results/${(pos_code)}/`,
            { 
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'JWT ' +  sessionStorage.getItem('token')
                },
                data: {
                    body: pos_title
                }
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: QUERY,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        }) 
    }
}
```

In the corresponding `views.py`, the `print(body_data)` is empty:

```
class GetQueryDataAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {'id': request.user.id}
        if kwargs:
            data['survey_id'] = kwargs.get('survey_id')
            data['pos_code'] = kwargs.get('pos_code')
        if data['survey_id'] == 94:
            body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
            body_data = json.loads(body_unicode)
            print(body_data)
        serializer = GetQueryDataSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Maybe its scope issue in your javascript. Double check the `pos_title`'s var scope.

Comment: Are you doing this request from the browser? Axios CAN use a GET request with a body, however the underlying network request Axios uses is an XMLHttpRequest which does not support it.

Comment: Yes, from the browser. Guess I should have kept reading as further down it does go on to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keith Brewster, Axios uses XMLHttpRequest which does not support sending data in the body of a request. One solution would be to do what David Ryan suggested and add `pos_title` to part of the URL. This creates some headaches though if there are spaces in the `pos_title` which there are in my case.

However, in my case, I decided to do filtering on the client-side, so keeping things as they were, and filtering the response was sufficient to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to modify your API URL, add pos_title as a query parameter.
This will get around any issues you may have in relation to sending a request body in a GET request. If you must send a request body, it sounds like you should be using a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to the same question I am posting the reply using your code:

You have to provide params with the get request like.

```
export function getQuery(pos_code, id) {
if (id === 94) {
    var strArray = pos_code.split(' - ');
    pos_code = strArray[0];
    var pos_title = strArray[1];
}
return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(
        `${URL}/api/survey/${(id)}/results/${(pos_code)}/`,
        { 
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' +  sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            params: {
                'title': pos_title
            }
        }
    )
}
```

}

And in the django part one can get the query_params as below:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    title = request.query_params['pos_title']
```